# Why did Ong Khan offer Temujin (young Gengis Khan) a position?

Tags: mongol-empire, mongolia

Why did [Ong Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toghrul) offer [Temujin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan#Early_life_and_family) (young Gengis kKan) a position? (after Temujin recognized him as his father)  I mean it seems that after the death of Temujin's father, Ong Khan did nothing to help and Temujin did not seek out help from him, but suddenly at some point Temujin recognized Ong Khan as his father and was offered a position.

Comment: I don't understand the question - isn't it normal patronage to offer positions once you've recognized someone as your son?  That is the structure of most tribal societies.  I don't understand why this is confusing.  What position was offered? What date?

Comment: my understanding of this  is from extra credits on youtube so it might not be totally accurate but basically after Temujin's father died  Ong Khan gave them no help nor did he do anything when Temujin was arrested for the murder of his brother then suddenly after Temujin recognizes Ong Khan as his father but can offer him nothing he is offered a position

Comment: Please update the question with that information and links to youtube if you have them.

Comment: "Suddenly after Temujin recognizes Ong Khan as his father... he is offered a position". Seems to back up @Mark C. Wallace simple explanation. Perhaps you want to know why Temujin recognized Ong Khan at that specific time?

Comment: The question I guess is why is Ong Khan treating this outcast criminal Temujin like an actual son?  Is the act of recognizing someone as your father so astounding that Ong Khan cares that Temujin an outcast and criminal recognized him as his father?

Comment: He was the blood brother of Temujin's real father. He probably knew him beforehand. He hated the Tatar and the Merkit that had enslaved him. Beeing recognized by Temujin as his father gains him a valid reason to wage war against those two ennemies, which he really wanted AND gives him a son that seems gifted and is also close of adulthood. In other words, he gains two valuable things, to do what he wishes, for nothing.

Answer (score 6):

**Why did Ong Khan offer Temujin a position?**

[Toghril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toghrul)’s (Ong Khan, died 1203)) acceptance of Temujin ([Genghis Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan)) as his ‘foster son’ held **advantages for both men**, and **Toghril’s relationship or ‘ceremonial kinship’ with Temujin’s deceased father** (they had been andas or blood brothers) made the ‘alliance’ all the more likely. On the latter point, Jack Weatherford, in *[Genghis Khan and the Making of the Modern World](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Genghis_Khan_and_the_Making_of_the_Moder.html?id=IVRtAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)* says:

> Temujin’s father, [Yesugei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesugei) .....
> had once been the anda of Ong Khan, and they had fought together
> against many enemies. The tie between the men had been stronger than
> merely patron and vassal because when they were quite young, Yesugei
> helped Ong Khan become khan of the [Kereyid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keraites) people by overthrowing his
> uncle, the Gur-khan, or supreme ruler. In addition, they had fought
> together against the [Merkid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkit) and were allied at the time of Temujin’s
> birth, when Yesugei was on the campaign against the Tatars.

[image]

*Mongol Empire c. 1207 showing the different tribes. [Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mongol_Empire_c.1207.png).*

For Toghril / Ong Khan, there was not just the fact that Temujin (and his two brothers who were also accepted as ‘foster sons’ at the same time) was the son of his anda; he was also a young man with a growing reputation for daring and initiative. Toghril had plenty of enemies, including members of his own family, and saw enough in Temujin to offer him the leadership of a group of young warriors (which Temujin declined).

Accepting Temujin proved to be a smart move for, when Toghril was later deposed by an uncle, Temujin helped him regain his position. Prior to that, Toghril had helped Temujin when his wife [Börte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6rte) had been taken captive.

---

**Why did Temujin seek out Ong Khan?**

Weatherford explains steppe culture further and one reason why Temujin sought out Toghril / Ong Khan

> According to steppe culture, politics were conducted through the idiom
> of male kinship. To be allies, men had to belong to the same family,
> and therefore every alliance between men not connected through biology
> had to be transformed into ceremonial or fictive kinship. Thus, with
> Temujin’s father and the would-be Kereyid leader having been
> ceremonial brothers as andas, Temujin now sought to be treated as a
> son to the old man.

Temujin, recently married, did this by using his wife Börte’s dowry (which he would normally have given to his father):

> Börte thus joined Temüjin’s family, bringing a sable coat as dowry.
> Temüjin gave the sable coat as a present to the powerful KEREYID khan
> Toghril (later ONG KHAN),

*Source: Christopher P. Atwood, '[Encyclopedia of Mongolia and the Mongol empire](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Encyclopedia_of_Mongolia_and_the_Mongol.html?id=I9dzQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)' (2004)*

In the turbulent world of the rivalries of the Mongol clans, a powerful ally such as Toghril / Ong Khan would prove very useful:

> By giving Ong Khan the wedding gift, Temujin was recognizing him as
> his father; and if Ong Khan accepted, he would be recognizing Temujin
> as his son and therefore entitled to protection.

*Source: Weatherford*

---

**Why didn't Temujin seek out Ong Khan earlier?**

The reasons for not seeking out Ong Khan earlier were most likely:

1. Temujin was only about 9 when his father died so, as a child, he had nothing to offer Ong Khan in return for his patronage. Further, the mere fact that he was a child would make it very unlikely that he would have been able to.
2. Temujin killed one of his half-brothers, bringing disgrace upon himself for quite some time. It seems unlikely that any potential patron would want to offer protection under such circumstances, and Temujin would have known that.
3. Later, Temujin was a captive slave and may have been in this state for as long as ten years.

In the years following his father Yisugei’s murder, Temujin and his family had endured much hardship. His mother [Hoelun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoelun) (Oelun)

> was seen as a paragon of heroic motherhood, raising her sons in great
> adversity.
>
> Ö’elün was abandoned on the steppe with her five children, Yisügei’s
> minor wife, Sülchigei, her two sons, and a certain number of
> retainers.

*Source: Atwood*

Then, at around the age of 15, Temujin had been involved in the killing of one of his half-brothers. Soon after, he became the captive of a rival clan but eventually managed to escape.

---

**Why didn't Ong Khan, do anything to help Temujin when the latter's father was killed by the [Tartars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatar_confederation) (or Tatars)?**

None of the sources offer any explanation for this, but there are a couple of pointers to possible reasons:

1. Ong Khan's realm bordered that of many rulers who were constantly seeking to expand their lands. The [Tartars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatars) were on Ong Khan's eastern border and, as vassals of the [Jurchen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurchen_people), may have been too powerful a force for to meddle with at the time.
2. Ong Khan does not appear to have been a particularly capable warlord. Temujin's family were outcasts so Ong Khan may have been neither inclined nor able to help them. He may also have been too preoccupied dealing with family rivals (he had had several of his brothers killed and was later temporarily deposed by an uncle).
3. According to Atwood, Ong Khan was not an especially admirable character:

> Despite the turbulent struggles of his youth, the [SECRET HISTORY OF
> THE MONGOLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_History_of_the_Mongols) portrays the mature Ong Khan as a lax and indecisive
> ruler, cruel to his brothers, excessively indulgent to his son...

Ong Khan's bond with his *anda* Yesugei may have been strong at one time, but such bonds did get broken (Temujin's childhood *anda* later turned against him). Also, we can gleam something of Ong Khan's character from his later actions: he deceived Temujin over a planned wedding and then fought against the adopted son who had sought (and been granted) his protection.

For the record, Temujin defeated Ong Khan at the [Battle of Jeje’er Heights](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=JtOqIc9t2qsC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=Battle%20of%20Jeje%E2%80%99er%20Heights&source=bl&ots=gwcOLcrYry&sig=ACfU3U0-hoIZUez4aDbyfG4Fj9u3bNBWQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE5vLS48LqAhWHyYsBHYBfAegQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Battle%20of%20Jeje%E2%80%99er%20Heights&f=false) in 1203.

*Other sources:*

*Don Nardo, '[Genghis Khan and the Mongol Empire](https://books.google.dm/books?id=RIhmDwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)' (2010)*

*Christopher P. Atwood, '[The Sacrificed Brother in the "Secret History of the Mongols"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43193541?seq=1)'. In Mongolian Studies, Vol. 30/31 (2008 and 2009), pp. 189-206.*

Comment: I get that part but from what I'm aware of Ong Khan did not do too much after Yesugei's death, neither care for his family or avenge Yesugei's death even though Yesugei had identified the tribe responsible upon his deathbed.   
And I guess why did Temujin not seek out Ong Khan immediately? it just feels so out of place

Comment: My sources didn't say anything on that but Temujin was only 8 or 9 when his father died. My guess is that he was too young to be of much use to Ong Khan, maybe too young to go take such an initiative.

Comment: Also, according to Atwood, Ong Khan was not a particularly nice character so I guess that he would only have helped if he had seen some advantage for it in himself. If so, this would not be the only time a blood brother didn't honour his 'vow' - for example, Temujin's *anda* eventually turned against him.